# Removing duplicate rows within a trigger in SQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, duplicates

So I've made table1 and table2 and a trigger such that when there's an insert on table1, data gets inserted into table2 from table1. I then go another step with another trigger where after insert on table2, it inserts into another table, table3 with data from table2. The trigger in place is 'FOR EACH ROW', so unfortunately, when a second insert happens on table1, it goes into table2, and table3 reads in the new, second row, AND the first row again.

Ideally to prevent this from happening, or to reduce the impact, it would make sense to remove duplicates at the end or at the start of a respective trigger so it's not exponentially filling up tables with duplicate rows. However, I've not been able to find a way to do it thus far within a trigger. Is it even possible? Any help? The tables also do not have Primary or Foreign Keys. Thanks in advance.

An example of what I've tried so far:

```
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM table2 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, ...);
```

Though I think this is for SQLite? As I've seen this working for SQLite databases, whereas here I just get an error saying it can't recognise the column rowid.

I also tried WHERE NOT EXISTS during insert, which works for not inserting duplicates in the first place, however I need an update as part of the trigger which changes some column values, so it won't work in this case as the rows will always be different from their initial insert.

Comment: I am not clear where you wish to stop the duplicates, table1, table2 or table3

Comment: table2 and table3. Both within triggers.

Comment: @BurakkuDrMario `for each row` does not mean that it will loop through all the rows. It basically means that all those rows which have been recently modified.

Comment: I'm no clearer on what you are trying to do here - you seem to be saying that you will accept 'duplicate' entries in table1 but want to insert into table2 if not entry exists in table2 or update table2 if they do, same with table3. If that's the case then an insert ..on duplicate key version if insert may be all you need.